# Qt Qdialog не возвращается к заданному размеру

Tags: windows, qt

Здравствуйте. Проблема в следующем. 
Создал себе Qdialog для вывода информации. Добавил к нему кнопку максимального расширения и дабы при последующих запусках окно раскрывалось не на весь экран (если его таким закрыли - развернутым полностью), добавил следующий код перед показом окна: "окно->resize(640, 480);"
При первом запуске он срабатывает и окно становится нужного размера (и если я просто растяну окно, тоже вернет к первоначальному), а вот при нажатии на максимальным размер, закрытии окна и повторном запуске получается следующее: 
[image: Все плохо]

Элементы на окне стали подстать размеру, а вот окно нет. Что делать и как исправлять, чтобы получилась возможность, если окно было закрыто при максимальном разрешении, открылось оно снова с первоначальным?
Вариант с "удалить окно и создать заново" не предлагать.
adjustSize(); - такой же результат.
результат ошибки такой: 
"setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 640x480+519+264 on QWidgetWindow/'briefWindow'. Resulting geometry:  1680x987+0+23 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 93x93, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 640x480+0+23 on QWidgetWindow/'briefWindow'. Resulting geometry:  1680x987+0+23 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 93x93, maximum size: 16777215x16777215)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ следующий. Чтобы отменить решил максимального расширения окна нужно выполнить 
windows->shownormal();
а после уже windwos ->resize(x,y); ну или setgeometry, чтобы указать где появляться.